# How does '%.*g' % (6,k) work in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I have the following piece of code: (Python 2.7)

```
k = 4535.65463456
out = '%.*g' % (6,k)
print str(out)
```

Output: `4535.65`

I am not able to understand the working of `'%.*g' % (6,k)`. Since I not familiar with this syntax and don't know what this is called, I am not even able to google it. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://pyformat.info/ : Parametrized precision:

`'%.*s = %.*f' % (3, 'Gibberish', 3, 2.7182)`, it's like `"%6g" % k`

Comment: Thank you very much @Jean-François Fabre. Could you put your comment as an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: It's the old syntax for `'{:.{prec}g}'.format(k, prec=6)`, see the Parametrized formatssection here: https://pyformat.info/. Which in turn is the old syntax for this: `f'{k:.{prec}g}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C-borrowed syntax `"%6g"` you're able to tell python to display your float with a maximum of six digits (if the number isn't too large).

It means that if the integer part of the number has 4 digits, it will use the 2 remaining digits to print the most significant decimal part.

Now if we want to make it parametrizable, we have to generate the format string, which isn't very convienient, so Python introduced *Parametrized precision* in such strings.

```
'%.*g' % (6,k)
```

prints `k` with 6 digits max.

Now you'll be better of the "new" formatting using `format`, which allows "nested" formatting to generate the outer formatting (so no need for intricate `.*` syntax):

```
'{:.{prec}g}'.format(k, prec=6)    # courtesy of Dan comment
```

Here `prec` isn't even a special keyword, just the parameter name passed as a function keyword. This is like:

```
'{:6g}'.format(k)
```

There's an entire website dedicated to python old & new style formats: https://pyformat.info/

(and there's also a newer syntax with Python 3.6 format strings... https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: *There's an entire website dedicated to python **older** & **old** style formats: https://pyformat.info/, they don't have the new string interpolation style yet

Comment: yeah, so I've seen. we should link to the new documentation, then.

Comment: Yeah, but to be honest I still prefer to reference the pyformat site because their examples are so clear! Once you've seen the string interpolation syntax once, I find it's easier to check the pyformat site for the actual formatting strings

Answer (score 0):

```
out = '%.*g' % (6,k)
```

that mean it will print the nember after ,6 ; look at '%.' %. = 4535. , that will be printed then '.*g' , * = 6 , the number after the ',' then g = 5 then number after 6